# Breading Asparagus

Tags: breadcrumbs, asparagus

Making asparagus ”breadsticks”

“Dip the asparagus first into the flour, then the egg and finally into the bread crumb mixture.”

I’m skeptical that flour will stick to a smooth asparagus.

Flour will stick to meat, maybe because of surface moisture— though doubt wet vegetables would get an even flour coating.  Maybe flour is lipophilic?

Getting back to breading the asparagus—should I try the egg first? Or maybe coating asparagus with butter then doing flour, egg, breadcrumb?

Comment: Did you try it?  I would follow the directions you quoted.

Comment: Are you honestly suggesting that greasing the asparagus might make it more sticky?

Answer (score 1):

The general principle is that 'wet sticks to dry' and 'dry sticks to wet'. I'd expect you would get a light coating of flour just by dredging the asparagus spears through flour. Then following the rest of the recipe will give you the usual batter.